# Use vlc mosaic to display multi RTSP streams from Spydroid

Tags: vlc, rtsp, mosaic

I want to display two RTSP streams in VLC 2.2.4 in the same window but different sections. These streams are from Spydroid in the same local network. I know that mosaic can do such thing.
Below is the configuration file:

```
new channel1 broadcast enabled
setup channel1 input "rtsp://192.168.43.200:8086"
setup channel1 output #duplicate{dst=mosaic-bridge{id=1,width=640,height=480},select=video}

new channel2 broadcast enabled
setup channel2 input "rtsp://192.168.43.230:8086"
setup channel2 output #duplicate{dst=mosaic-bridge{id=2,width=640,height=480},select=video}

new mosaic broadcast enabled
setup mosaic input /Users/lovejoy/Downloads/bg640960.jpg
setup mosaic output #transcode{sfilter=mosaic,vcodec=mp4v,scale=1}:display

control channel2 play
control channel1 play
control mosaic play
```

Both of the configurations of two phones are the same:

```
Video Encoder: H.264
Resolution: 640*480
Framerate: 8fps
Bitrate: 2000kbps
```

I want to put two streams in a vertical layout, the run arguments like this:

```
vlc --vlm-conf /Users/lovejoy/Downloads/conf.vlm --mosaic-keep-aspect-ratio --mosaic-keep-picture --mosaic-position=2 --mosaic-order="1,2" --mosaic-offsets="0,0,0,480" --mosaic-width=640 --mosaic-height=960 --image-duration=-1
```

However, the result does not like what I want: two streams just bump at the top section, they do not show separately. Two streams compete for the same section (compete is the exact word because they show alternately until one stream disconnect).

[This is the vlc screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOAmi.jpg)

[This is the terminal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBy1J.png)

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: I find the same problem [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2232604) and [here](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=119288) without any solutions.

Comment: Try this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59180160/mosaic-of-rtsp-streams-vlc-3-0-8