# Display two RTSP streams in mosaic mode on VLC

Tags: vlc, rtsp

I have two IP cameras who's stream I would like to display as a mosaic in VLC.
I'm able to display each stream separately from the Media -> Open Network Stream menu, however I haven't been able to display both at the same time.

I've looked around and tried [4](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_HowTo/Make_a_mosaic/) [slightly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59180160/mosaic-of-rtsp-streams-vlc-3-0-8) [different](https://alex.mamchenkov.net/2014/11/27/vlc-mosaic-multiple-rstp-streams/comment-page-1/) [variations](https://gist.github.com/Vankalif/c61bd6c227c938572b3f2788b0e2c615) on how to display multiple streams in a mosaic fashion and each time it failed to produce results.

When executing my VLM config file (.vlm) it launches VLC but doesn't do much else. I'm locked on the starting screen.

Something that's bothering me in some of the above examples is the use of an ip address and a port in the `standard` parameter of the `#transcode` command as in :

```
setup background output #transcode{sfilter=mosaic,vcodec=mp2v,vb=10000,scale=1}:bridge-in{delay=400,id-offset=100}:standard{access=udp,mux=ts,url=239.255.12.42,sap,name="mosaic"}
```

My cameras have a parameter called `Multicast Video address` which looks similar so I've tried using that but I still get the same results.

I was also wondering if there is any kind of log in VLC that I could look into to see any undisplayed error message ?

Answer (score 0):

After looking a bit further I stumbled accross [this](https://amcrest.com/forum/ip-cameras-f18/vlc-mosaic-monitor-%E2%80%93-howto-tile-view-of-all-ip-c-t13564.html) solution that worked for me.
I will look into further to see what exactly made it work and edit this answer then.
For now the two streams have a 1s delay compared to the live webservers of the cameras.

```
# 1 ##

new IPC1 broadcast enabled

setup IPC1 option rtsp-tcp=enabled

setup IPC1 option rtsp-user="admin"

setup IPC1 option rtsp-pwd="admin"

setup IPC1 input "rtsp://192.168.1.30:554/stream1"

setup IPC1 output #duplicate{dst=mosaic-bridge{id=1},select=video}



## 2 ##

new IPC2 broadcast enabled

setup IPC2 option rtsp-tcp=enabled

setup IPC2 option rtsp-user="admin"

setup IPC2 option rtsp-pwd="admin"

setup IPC2 input "rtsp://192.168.1.31:554/stream1"

setup IPC2 output #duplicate{dst=mosaic-bridge{id=2},select=video}



## MOSAIC ##

new mosaic broadcast enabled

setup mosaic option image-fps=12/1

setup mosaic input "cea_bg.jpg"

setup mosaic output #transcode{sfilter=mosaic{width=1920,height=1080,rows=2,cols=1,position=1,order="1,2"},vcodec=mp4v}:display



## Launch ##

control IPC1 play

control IPC2 play

control mosaic play
```